# Spring Security: Secure endpoint based on client authority

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, kotlin

I'm currently using Spring Security's OAuth2 to implement authorization across a number of micro services. Our `AuthService` performs all of the authentication with OAuth2 tokens etc and can create users.

Consider two clients: Client A and Client B.

Client A has authorities: `CREATE_USER, CREATE_POST`
Client B has authorities: `READ_USER`

(Yes we could use a scope instead, but this is just an example!)

**Aim:**

Only Client A, which has the authority `CREATE_USER`, should be allowed to create a user. Users are creating by posting to `/users`.

**Problem:**

The problem is that when I send a POST request to the /users endpoint with the basic authentication header for Client A, the `CREATE_USER` authority is not found because the request hit the `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` and the only authority found is `ROLE_ANONYMOUS` and I receive the following:

```
10:38:34.852 [http-nio-9999-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /users; Attributes: [#oauth2.throwOnError(#oauth2.hasAuthority('CREATE_USER))]
10:38:34.852 [http-nio-9999-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
10:38:34.854 [http-nio-9999-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@a63e3e8, returned: -1
10:38:34.856 [http-nio-9999-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
```

One incredibly hacky solution would be to register a custom security filter that reads the basic auth header and verifies that a client's name is equal to Client A, but this will not work for a third client, Client C which also has the `CREATE_VIEWER` authority, as the name and not the authorities are verified here.

```
// UsersController.kt
@PostMapping("/users")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
fun createUser(): String {
    return "Created user!"
}
```

Client Configuration

```
override fun configure(clients: ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer?) {
    clients!!.inMemory()
        .withClient("ClientA")
        .scopes("all")
        .authorities("CREATE_USER", "CREATE_POST")
        .authorizedGrantTypes("refresh_token", "password")
        .and()
        .withClient("ClientB")
        .scopes("all")
        .authorities("READ_USER")
        .authorizedGrantTypes("refresh_token", "password")

}
```

WebSecurityConfigurerAdaptor impl

```
override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
    http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access")
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/users").access("hasAuthority('CREATE_USER')")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()
}

override fun configure(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
}

@Bean
open fun authenticationProvider(): DaoAuthenticationProvider {
    val authProvider = DaoAuthenticationProvider()
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userCredentialService)
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoderService)
    return authProvider
}
```

Comment: If you want to use HTTP basic to authenticate the /users endpoint, don't you have to actually declare that? It's nothing to do with OAuth at that point.

Comment: Note that you also don't include /users in the request matchers for that filter. So the filter won't be used for those requests.

Comment: @DaveSyer I've tried enabling HTTP Basic for the endpoint, as you're right, it's most certainly not an OAuth request. However it's currently expecting the basic auth credentials to be related to a principal and not a client. Error is: https://gist.github.com/maxkramer/0594f73a00b84b35f3b4521e96c33168

Comment: This seems to be because it's hitting the authentication provider which doesn't a principal/user for a client.

Comment: A client can be a principal, but you might need to adapt it (there's a user details service in your code so I assume that's what it is doing). You haven't responded to my comment about the request matchers (this filter simply isn't being executed in /users).

Comment: @DaveSyer you're right - I did however create a separate configuration (see gist) which is now triggering the basic auth.

Comment: @DaveSyer I've just verified that the request is indeed hitting the user details service. Is there a way of proxying it over to the clients detail service to be verified against the client configuration that I have already created? As you can see - the clients are being stored in memory.

Comment: @DaveSyer or alternatively is there a way of asserting that requests to this endpoint will contain a client and not a user, and should therefore be looked up against the client details service and not the user details service?

Comment: Your updated configuration (in the gist not in the question yet) does now match the /users endpoint, but I don't see anywhere that you plug the client credentials into the authentication manager.

Comment: @DaveSyer the client credentials are plugged into the authentication manager using the `configure(clients: ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer?)` method in the OP. Please see the following gist for the full configuration file: https://gist.github.com/maxkramer/5afc74173b04ecd33ef628ca38447ab3

Comment: If you put a complete sample in GitHub it will be easier. I'm on PTO but if there's a sample I might be able to fix it and send a PR on Monday.